# Mocked function is called twice, should be called once

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing a functional component. In one scenario a mocked function is called twice, does anyone know why? When I comment the `useEffect` hooks it works fine and gets called once, but there is no code related to that on the `useEffect`.

Here is my test:

```
   it('sends correct payload when user deletes a comment', async () => {
      const spy = jest.spyOn(CommentsService, 'deleteComment').mockImplementation(mockDeleteComment);
      const { container } = render(
        withProvider(queryClient, <GeneralParametersSections {...generalParametersProps} />),
      );
      const commentsSection = container.querySelector('.comments-section')!;
      const comments = commentsSection.querySelectorAll('.comment-item');
      expect(comments).toHaveLength(1);
      expect(comments[0].textContent).toContain(commentsMock[0].content);

      const firstCommentDeleteButton = comments[0].querySelector('.comment-item-actions .fa-trash')!;

      await fireEvent.click(firstCommentDeleteButton);

      expect(mockDeleteComment).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mockDeleteComment).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/general_parameters_page_comments');

      spy.mockRestore();
    });
```

I've received 2 in `expect(mockDeleteComment).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);`

Comment: Are you using `jest.spyOn(CommentsService, 'deleteComment').mockImplementation(mockDeleteComment)` in another test?

Comment: @MatiasBertoni yes, but i remove and clean the mock beforech

Comment: try adding an `afterEach` that calls `jest.clearAllMocks()`

Comment: @MatiasBertoni sorry I mean after each, I've already called it

Comment: Place a breakpoint somewhere `mockDeleteComment` and debug the test to see who else is calling it. YOu can use the debugger call stack to see where the call came from